# Apache Commons Email - Sending emails in a thread

Tags: java, scala, apache-commons-email

I'm using Apache Commons Email to send notification emails to my users.
Some emails share a topic and I would like them to be grouped in a same Conversation or Thread.

I couldn't find any out-of-the-box feature in Apache commons Email documentation.

Is there any way to have email grouped in a same conversation using this library?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Send emails with same subject. Those email will then appear in same group

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue. I tried that already

Comment: In case of Gmail, grouping email should be enabled in inbox settings. Make sure of that as well

Comment: My user base is using Outlook with grouping enabled. I am using this setup to test.